# Captured video in Adobe Premiere - is the next step to make subclips?

Tags: premiere, editing

I've captured a lot of mini dv tape footage in adobe premiere which now sits in the library box in the bottom left. I've logged time in and out points of clips I want to keep with pen and paper. Should my next step be to do that by creating sub clips? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow is really up to whatever works for you.  Unfortunately, you kind of did things backwards from the workflow I would have used.

With mini-DV tapes, the fastest thing I've found is to do the clip logging with the batch capture tool and then run a batch capture to have each clip captured as an individual file. It does take a little bit of practice to get good at using the batch capture tool for logging, but it makes it easy to recapture a particular clip down the road and organizes clips much more easily for you.

After the fact, your best bet is probably just to drop each clip in its own sequence or simply insert them all on to your timeline and work from there if you have a decent idea of how you want the rough edit to look.

You could also split the clips if you wanted as long as you are using DV format which will not lose additional quality in each additional export.  It really comes down to whatever will be the easiest for you to work with though.  Everyone can be a bit different when it comes down to how they want to organize their stuff.

Comment: my filming skills are not good enough for the batch capturing and because I'm self-shooting often with a lot going on around me, then its better I watch it first, decide what is good and go back to create clips. I was hoping to create subclips because then I don't actually have to physically do anything to the file. It just keeps the meta-info of in and out point.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what batch capture is. Batch capture means you log your clips in advance while watching it, then have it capture each clip individually.

Comment: I've just watched this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQQxR7ZehJ0 about batch capturing. Because I have so much footage and I can't remember what it all is, then I cant say 'oh this is the in point' and 'this is the out point' without watching it first in a lot of cases. Also I'm kind of making backups of the footage here too. However, I'm totally learning by doing here, so I might end up facepalming later on.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of face palming as you learn, but that is half the fun. :)

Comment: I've seen tutorials that talk about using subclips as an alternative if you have long clips of footage like an interview that is not by default a series of small clips. Where do you recommend I go from here? I've got a project with a bunch of .avi files captured in the library (1hr long each). Whats the best way to edit them onto the timeline? Can you recommend some resources?